# How do i show an image in google Colab?

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

When I use

```
cv2.imshow(img)
```

colab throws a `DisabledFunctionError` (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935).
Using cv2_imshow(img) I am getting another error, `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip')`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Using cv2.imshow(img) in Google Colab returns this output:

```
DisabledFunctionError: cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessions
to crash; see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935.
As a substitution, consider using
  from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
```

Accordingly, you can simply use:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = "yourImage.png"
img = cv2.imread(img) # reads image
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: cv2 uses BGR with jpg so your image might look weird. If it does, you should use `image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` to convert your BGR to RGB

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
cv2_imshow(img)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't use OpenCv but PIL instead. I compress images as ultra low quality JPG (quality 20).

As images are sent over the internet to your PC, it's better than using raw OpenCv. You can probably get the same result with imsave instead instead of PIL.

```
from ipywidgets import Image as ipywidgets_Image
from IPython.display import display as ipython_display
from PIL import Image as pil_Image
import time
import numpy as np
from io import BytesIO

def update_image_jpg(np_img, widget_img):
  pil_img = pil_Image.fromarray(np_img, mode="RGB")
  with BytesIO() as output_file:
      pil_img.save(output_file, format="jpeg", quality=20)
      png_data = output_file.getvalue()
  # Updates the image in the browser
  widget_img.value=png_data

######
# We'll update the image data in this container
widget_img = ipywidgets_Image()
# Call this only once 
ipython_display(widget_img) 

# Draw a coloured spiral
np_img = np.zeros((400,600,3), dtype=np.uint8)

p = np.array([200,300], dtype=int)
for i in range(1000):
  r = i/10
  theta=i/20
  p2 = p + r * np.array([ np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta) ])
  (y,x) = p2.astype(int)
  rgb = np.array([100+r, 100*(1+np.sin(theta)), 100*(1+np.cos(theta))], dtype=np.uint8)
  np_img[y:y+8, x:x+2, :] = rgb

  update_image_jpg(np_img, widget_img)
  time.sleep(1.0/60.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also display images in the markdown/Text cell in Colab. Create a Text cell and then you will have a top bar with icons. Select the image icon corresponding to “Insert images” and then choose from you local machine the image.