# DisabledFunctionError: cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessionsto crash

Tags: python, opencv, google-cloud-platform, pycharm, anaconda

**DisabledFunctionError: cv2.imshow() is disabled in Colab, because it causes Jupyter sessions
to crash; se  **

```
import cv2
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow

image = cv2.imread("/content/runnnn.jfif")
lane_image = np.copy(image)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(lane_image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

cv2.imshow("result",gray)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. Please add more details and clarify your question!

Comment: code  dosent run

Comment: Use Visual Studio Code.

Comment: The reason the OP used colab is most likely because they wanted to use the free GPU

Comment: The answer provided by @DapperDuck seems to be correct, you can check out the alternative Stack [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506138).

Answer (score 9):

Replace `cv2.imshow("result",gray)` with this:

```
cv2_imshow(gray)
```

You imported `cv2_imshow` correctly, you now just need to call the method.

Answer (score 7):

`cv2.imshow()` is disabled in colab. So, you can import this replacement function which addresses this problem.

`from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow`

and use `cv2_imshow()` instead of `cv2.imshow()` where needed.

Answer (score 4):

in google colab, the **cv2.imshow("img", img)** is disabled because it causes Jupyter sessions
to crash; see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3935.

you can use **cv2_imshow(img)**.